# error ao instalar github npm

Tags: javascript, node.js, git, github, npm

Instalei o npm e configurei meu proxy depois disso quando tento instalar qualquer biblioteca por exemplo o git hub, ele aparece esses erros:

```
npm ERR! node v6.11.3
npm ERR! npm  v3.10.10
npm ERR! code HPE_INVALID_CONSTANT
npm ERR! Parse Error
```

Baseado em um tutorial de configuração:

> npm config set proxy http://usuario:senha@host_proxy:porta_proxy

em configurações da rede local (lan) (no meu windowns) 
endereço: plimbr.com.br porta: 8080
e meu user e senha da rede é p454647 senha 12345

minha configuração a partir dessas informações coloquei assim:

`npm` config set proxy http://p454647:12345@plimbr.com.br:8080

Comment: Qual comando está tentando executar?

Comment: npm install github. Mas na verdade fiz outros testes e todos dão erro

Comment: Parecer estar relacionado com a sua configuração de proxy. Pode postá-la aqui?

Comment: @ruanmartinelli não sei se esta configurado corretamente

Answer (score 0):

Abra o cmd e escreva: npm config edit

depois disso o arquivo de configurações npm vai ser aberto. Ai é só alterar as configurações via http e https para esses itens que você colocou, aparentemente parece estar certo.

Comment: Deu certo! valeu